# Potential profile defined up to a constant

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, voltage, conventions

More of a clarification than an actual question. I'm doing exercises on graphing electric fields and the corresponding potential profiles, and i get the same potential profile as my professor, just shifted by a constant. Is it correct to state that since potential is defined up to a constant of integration, my solution is as good as hers?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: Choose a equipotential surface and add/subtract a constant to make its value the same as your professor’s value for the same contour.  You should then find you have identical mappings of the potential.